# Ember how to test my console.log wrapper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a log service that wraps console.log. I'm having difficulty testing it because console.log is async. I override console.log, but I'm still having async issues. The console.log function is being called after my assert.

```
wrapper(msg) {
  console.log.bind(console); //I am binding it because in my real code the console is looked up in a map.
  console.log(msg);
}

test('log() can handle valid mask', function (assert) {
  let passed = false;
  subject = this.subject();
  console.log = function() {
    passed = true;
  };  

  subject.wrapper('testing');                        
  assert.equal(passed, true);
});
```

How do I get it to wait for console.log to run? I attempted using promises, but I had no luck with them.

Comment: Any particular reason you are doing this instead of using Ember's built in Logger class?

Comment: Learning purposes, and having fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async from qunit

```
test('log() can handle valid mask', function (assert) {
  let passed = false;
  debugger;
  console.log = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
          passed = true;
    }, 0);
  };

  var done1 = assert.async();
  wrapper('testing');

  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.equal(passed, true);
    done1();
  }, 100);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/nozoruxori/edit?js,output
works fine

with Ember for async checking you can use `andThen` wrapper ( for async assertion )

also looks like `console.log.bind(console); //I am binding it because in my real code the console is looked up in a map.` miss something cause in this state it has no sense